# Export declaration file for JavaScript function in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm new to TypeScript and I want to know how to write declaration file for custom JavaScript function. I tried this, but it give me error "Could not find a declaration file for module './main'." and don't give any IntelliSense in index.ts file.

main.js

```
var maths={ sum:function (a,b){ console.log(a+b)}}
```

module.exports=maths;

index.ts

```
import * as mt from "./main"
mt.sum(2,5);
```

type.d.ts

```
 declare module 'main' {
export function sum(a:number,b:number):void }
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This import

```
import * as mt from "./main"
```

is looking for either `main.ts` or `main.d.ts` in the same directory as `index.ts`.

So one thing you can try is to rename `type.d.ts` to `main.d.ts` and remove `declare module 'main'` from it, leave just `export function sum` at the top level. When imported that way, module name is taken from the file name. Also, you might have to remove reference to `type.d.ts` from your project (or `tsconfig.json`) if you have one.

ALternatively, you can try to change the import to

```
import * as mt from "main"
```

so that imported module name matches exactly the name given in `declare module`.

Comment: Appreciate the answer and it works.One more thing need to ask should be both d.ts file and .js file in same folder ?

Comment: for import `from "./main"`, `main.js` file should be in the same folder where compiled `index.js` is.